# unable to click the image and redirect to a specific page

Tags: reactjs

searched for a while but cannot get an appropriate answer for my case.

I have a recipe website,

in home page, there are multiple recipes.

what I wanted to do is when users click into the image of the recipe, they will be redirected to the designated recipe page.

so I have made a Link component that applied on the image

```
                <Link to={`/detail/${recipe._id}`}>
                  <div className="recipePhoto">
                    <img src={recipe.imageUrl} alt={recipe.name} />
                  </div>
                </Link>
```

I have tested that it can generate a recipeId as I wanted

for below, I have also create a route
which I have already tested on postman, it works

```
recipeRouter.get("/detail/:_id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const foundRecipe = await recipeModel.findById(req.params._id);
    console.log(foundRecipe);
    res.status(200).send(foundRecipe);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send("cannot find the recipe gg");
  }
});
```

however, on the RecipePage.jsx which is the script as below
,I stuck, since I have no idea how to extract part of the URL and put it into my request.
I googled it and people said I could use {useParam} ,

but the url on their examples were input manually ,
not like mine, which is self-generated

so I have no idea of how to put them together,

feel like I missed some dots over there,
please advise,

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from axios;
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const SingleRecipe = (props) => {
  const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3001/detail/${??????}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setRecipe(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.response) alert(JSON.stringify(err.response.data));
      });
  }, [props.match.params._id]);

  return (
    <div className="recipeSession">
      <h1 className="recipeSessionHeader">Recipe</h1>
      <div className="recipesContainer">
        <div className="recipes">
          <ul className="recipeList">
            {recipe.map((recipe) => (
              <li key={recipe._id}>
                <div className="recipeName">
                  <h2 className="recipeNameHeader">{recipe.name}</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="recipePhoto">
                  <img src={recipe.imageUrl} alt={recipe.name} />
                </div>
                <div className="recipeIngredients">
                  <p>{recipe.ingredient}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="recipeInstruction">
                  <p>{recipe.instruction}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="recipeCookingTime">
                  <p> Cooking Time: {recipe.cookingTime}(minutes)</p>
                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SingleRecipe;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`useParams()`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) will return an object with the params you configured your route with as keys. So if for example your route path is `/detail/:_id`, your param is named `_id` and you can get it's value like this:

```
const { _id } = useParams();
```

Comment: I have seen ppl also create a path in route under routes in app.js
do you recommend me doing that as well, since I cannot tell the difference

Comment: @ksyu1113 What do you mean do I recommend? Don't you have a router set up? Your routing cannot work without it.